# Dependence of a sum on its summands

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials, summation, real-numbers

Suppose $\Delta_{K-1}=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^K_{>0}: x_1+x_2+\cdots x_K=1\}$  and we have the following function $G:\Delta_{K-1}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as an $n$-fold sum

$G(x_1,x_2,...,x_K) :=\sum_{i_1=1}^K \sum_{i_2=1}^K \cdots \sum_{i_n=1}^K x_{i_1} x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_n} F( x_{i_1}, x_{i_2},..., x_{i_n})$

where $n$ is fixed and $F:\mathbb{R}_{>0}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary function.

Is it possible to prove that if $F$ is chosen such that the function  $G(x_1,x_2,...,x_K)$ is constant on $\Delta_{K-1}$, then this constant, seen as a function of $K$, can only be a polynomial in $K$ ?

For example, if we choose $F( x_{i_1}, x_{i_2},..., x_{i_n}) = (x_{i_1} x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_n})^{-1}$, then $F$ makes $G$ constant on $\Delta_{K-1}$ and $G(x_1,x_2,...,x_K) = K^n = G(K)$, which is polynomial in $K$. Similarly, if we choose $F( x_{i_1}, x_{i_2},..., x_{i_n}) = x_{i_1}^{-1} +x_{i_2}^{-1}+\cdots x_{i_n}^{-1}$, then $G(x_1,x_2,...,x_K) = nK = G(K)$, which is again polynomial in $K$.

In other words, if we choose an $F$ that makes $G$ a constant independent of the $x_i$'s, then is it possible that this constant $G$, seen as a function of what was previously a fixed integer $K$, has a dependence on $K$ which is not polynomial ?

Comment: What you mean exactly by $F$ is such that the sum does not depend on any of the $x_i$'s? Is it something like: "$G(x_1\dots x_K) = \sum_{i_1=1}^K \sum_{i_2=1}^K \cdots \sum_{i_n=1}^K x_{i_1} x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_n} F( x_{i_1}, x_{i_2},..., x_{i_n})$ is constant on the set $\{x_1\dots x_K:\sum_{i=1}^Kx_i = 1\}$"?

Comment: If $K=1$ then $x_1=1$ and the $n$-fold sum consists of the single term
$$1^nF(1,1,\ldots,1),$$
so any function $F$ will do.

Comment: @ECL Yes, I edited the question. EDIT : $n$ is fixed.